# select2, simple_form and acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, simple-form, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to add tags to a model. I need it to function with the following features:

- Rendered as tags in the view using select2
- User can create their own tags (ie. enter new tag then 'space' or ',')
- User is prompted with existing tags to keep input consistant

i.e. the same way the "tags" box works on this site when posting a question!

I am 99% of the way there but each approach I take it seems that one part does not work.

Here are my software versions:

- select2-rails (3.5.7)
- simple_form (3.0.1)
- acts-as-taggable-on (4.0.0)
- Rails 4.03

Following Code: rendered correctly, but not able to add new tags before saving, prompt for existing tags works

```
@tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
<%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'tags', multiple: true}, collection: @tags, value_method: :name %>

$('.tags').select2({ 

    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    placeholder: "Add your tag here"
});
```

Following Code: rendered as a multi line text box, not tags via select2

```
@tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
<%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'tags', multiple: true}, collection: @tags, value_method: :name %>

$('.tags').select2({ 
    tags: true, 
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    placeholder: "Add your tag here"
});
```

Following Code: rendered correctly, and can add new tags, but not prompt to select existing tags

```
@tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
<%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'tags', multiple: true } %>

$('.tags').select2({ 
    tags: true, 
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    placeholder: "Add your tag here"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who finds this I ended up doing this to get it to work.

```
@tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.pluck(:name)
<%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'tags', multiple: true, data: {options: @tags} } %>

$('.tags').select2({ 
    tags: $('.tags').data('options'),
    tokenSeparators: [' ', ',']
});
```

Happy to hear if there is a cleaner method.